# Call methods of a separated class library project by using Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to create a separated class library project as the web service of an ASP.NET MVC project? (Actually, I want to have an MVC Project and a class library project as its web service to call methods by using Ajax in the web project)

I tried this as the URL of ajax request but Ajax couldn't find it: ('Mine' and 'Service' are namespaces; 'UserService' is the name of the class, and the 'SignUpUser' is the method I want to call:

```
url: "Mine.Service.UserService/SignUpUser"
```

Comment: Normally people create an API.

Comment: You can make calls to your library from an MVC controller, but no, you will not be able to call methods on a class that is not exposed through HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much better way to call your web service.

You can use the [WEB API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) in ASP.NET to expose your services and data rather than creating separated class library to call your web service